# Excel Separators when importing from Web

Tags: microsoft-excel

There is this very cool function in excel where you can import a data source from a web url.

I want to import Tabular Data from a Wikipedia page: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_Schweizer_Gemeinden

When I want to transform columns to numerical or decimal numbers in the importer it results in errors because of the comma separator and because of the thousand separator:

**Import without transformation:**

[image]

**Import when transforming columns either to decimal number or just numbers:**

[image]

I changed the Separator options to System or custom and replaced them with those glyphs, but this has no effect.

I could just open the table in VS Code and Search & Replace the separators but I wonder if there is a way when I can't change the source.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you confirm are you trying to achieve this? **[Refer Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/OfQErnB)**

Comment: Almost. The Column "Einwohner" (Resident) should also be integers. But it doesn't recognize integers with thousand separators `'`

Comment: Now look at this **[here](https://imgur.com/gallery/GBtMRGR)**

Comment: awesome. that's the endgoal, yes

Comment: So I have replaced the commas with dots as well as the `'` this one with nothing. And then changed the data type. Here it **[is](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckUsWWtVx9DZOMtwt?e=fp2kCx)** using `Power Query`

Comment: Fantastic. thank you, but my initial question was if this would also be possible with a url as data source. because then I can't just replace the characters the way I want to because I cant change te source in a text editor

Comment: No, how are you importing it using `Power Query` or not? You are not chaning the source in a text editor, instead you are changing everything of the source using `Power Query` So when you import back to excel you get what you desire. Hope I am able to explain, if not then you can open the file to see for your own.

Comment: Are you able to understand?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I suggest you replace only the `'` with nothing, and then set the appropriate columns to Number or Integer using the `German(Germany)` culture. The column with the `'` thousands separator is using the Swiss culture, but, for some reason, Power Query (Excel) does not seem to recognize that.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir, i will try that now.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes, I understand. But I don't get how to do the replacement of the characters in `PowerQuery` I find that UI confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to designate comma as the decimal character in the computer
while you do this import.

This is done in
*Control Panel > Region > Additional settings ...*.
Exchange the settings for "Decimal symbol" and
"Digit grouping symbol", do the import, close Excel,
and then exchange them back.